# Print first N rows per group -> Remove all docker images except newest N for each image name

Tags: shell, docker, awk

Use case: Clean up disk space by removing old docker images

Taking this images as an example.

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                                        IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
gateway             2f280f169e9b018c3ee155e47e176c3418349b90   846b7ba3595c        9 hours ago         597MB
gateway             latest                                     846b7ba3595c        9 hours ago         597MB
gateway             2f280f169e9b018c3ee155e47e176c3418349b90   e47e176c3418        9 hours ago         597MB
order               2f280f169e9b018c3ee155e47e176c3418349b90   0e01f7594e4a        9 hours ago         591MB
order               latest                                     0e01f7594e4a        9 hours ago         591MB
order               2f280f169e9b018c3ee155e47e176c3418349b90   7e176c34183a        9 hours ago         591MB
payment             2f280f169e9b018c3ee155e47e176c3418349b90   e2053260d33e        9 hours ago         590MB
payment             latest                                     e2053260d33e        9 hours ago         590MB
payment             2f280f169e9b018c3ee155e47e176c3418349b90   169e9b018c3e        9 hours ago         590MB
price-offer         2f280f169e9b018c3ee155e47e176c3418349b90   5a4726a65fbd        9 hours ago         589MB
```

I would like to remove all images but always keep the newest N images for each name/repository.

So here I have 3 gateway, 3 order, 3 payment and 1 price-offer images.
If I run the script with N=2 it should remove the oldest gateway, order, payment image and dont remove the single price-offer image.
If I run the script with N=1 it will only keep the newest image for each repository/name.

Currently I have this:

```
docker images | tail -n+2 | awk '{ print $1,$3 }' | sort -r
```

which gives me:

```
gateway  e47e176c3418
gateway 846b7ba3595c
gateway 846b7ba3595c
order 7e176c34183a 
order 0e01f7594e4a
order 0e01f7594e4a
payment 169e9b018c3e
payment e2053260d33e
payment e2053260d33e
price-offer 5a4726a65fbd
```

But I am struggling with the part which just prints the first N rows for each image (where $1 is the same).

Comment: If every image was created `9 hours ago` then how to get the oldest?

Comment: the output of `docker images` sorts it already, the first image which is printed is the newest one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk` command to list all latest `N` images:

```
docker images | awk -v N=2 '++freq[$1] <= N'
```

To remove all oldest images and keep newest `N` images use:

```
docker images | awk -v N=2 '++freq[$1] > N {print $3}' | xargs -p docker rmi
```